# GNU-screen disable scrollback

Tags: gnu-screen

How to disable scrollback (^A[ESC]) mode in screen and just have it straight up print to the terminal instead (using the builtin scroll of my terminal emulator)?

I am using screen on gnome-terminal across an ssh session
Since the terminal has builtin scroll capabilities, I just want to be able to use the scrollwheel on the mouse to scroll as opposed to using ^A[ESC]

Answer (score 0):

In command mode (`^A:`), set `scrollback 0`.

A few notes:

- The current length of the scrollback buffer in lines is shown (among other stuff) by the `info` command (after the plus character).
- Using the mouse wheel will not give the same experience that screen can offer

  - the terminal's scrollback contains exactly data that was actually displayed
  - data from inactive windows is not available
  - split windows will show as-is
- I am answering an 8 year old question that came up in a web search - the answer was in `man screen`.